# Calculate soccer matches combinations without repetition

Tags: php, arrays, math

So, I have an array like this, filled with teams:

```
array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

At every tournament, we have `TotalNumberOfTeams-1` rounds (dates) with matches. (1st loop)

At every round, we have `TotalNumberOfTeams/2` matches. (2 loop)

How is possible to calculate the combinations for this result:

```
       Date   Date   Date   Date   Date
Match: 0-1    0-2    0-3    0-4    0-5
Match: 2-3    1-5    1-4    1-3    1-2
Match: 4-5    3-4    2-5    2-4    3-5
```

*/w common words: Every team plays every round with different team*

Code to calculate rounds, matches and dates:

```
// Rounds
for($i=1; $i <= ($teamsNum - 1); $i++) {
  // Matches
  for($z=0; $z < ($teamsNum / 2); $z++){
    //some code here
  }
  // Calculate next date
  $mdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mdate. ' + x days'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [round-robin tournament algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).

In short:
Make two rows of commands, every top command plays with corresponding command form lower row. I number is odd, one command rests.

Shift all command **except for the first** in circular manner

```
0  1
2  3
=====
0  2
3  1
====
0  3
1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

there is an answer with code example - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#php

just use $k=2 for yours calculations